# Gstreamer with Python and PyQt does not work very well

Tags: pyqt, gstreamer, raspbian, python-gstreamer

I have two Raspberry Pi. and want stream video from one to another. for do this I used the following command on first Raspberry Pi to stream video :

```
raspivid -t 999999 -w 1080 -h 720 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | \gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 \! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=serverIp port=5000
```

in the second Raspberry Pi I used the following pyqt code to capture streamed video :

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GstVideo
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Create GStreamer pipeline
        self.Video_pipeline()

##############################################################################
#VIDEO Pipeline
#|
#|
#V
##############################################################################
    def Video_pipeline(self):
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
        self.tcpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('tcpclientsrc','tcpsrc')
        self.tcpsrc.set_property("host", '192.168.1.9')
        self.tcpsrc.set_property("port", 5000)
        self.gdepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('gdpdepay', 'gdepay')
        self.rdepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtph264depay', 'rdepay')
        self.avdec = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_h264', 'avdec')
        self.vidconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'vidconvert')
        self.asink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autovideosink', 'asink')
        self.asink.set_property('sync', False)

        self.pipeline.add(self.tcpsrc)
        self.pipeline.add(self.gdepay)
        self.pipeline.add(self.avdec)
        self.pipeline.add(self.rdepay)
        self.pipeline.add(self.vidconvert)
        self.pipeline.add(self.asink)

        self.tcpsrc.link(self.gdepay)
        self.gdepay.link(self.rdepay)
        self.rdepay.link(self.avdec)
        self.avdec.link(self.vidconvert)
        self.vidconvert.link(self.asink)
##############################################################################
#^
#|
#|
#VIDEO Pipeline
##############################################################################

    def start(self):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.pipeline_A.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        #self.showMaximized()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It worked fine. now I need to design a GUI. I wrote this code:

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GstVideo
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        #creat Simple Window
        container = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        container.setWindowTitle('Test1')
        container.connect('destroy', self.quit)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        self.winId = container.winId()
        self.resize(480, 320)

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)

                # Create GStreamer pipeline
        self.Video_pipeline()

        # Create bus to get events from GStreamer pipeline
        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
        self.bus.connect('message::error', self.on_error)
        self.bus.connect('message::eos', self.on_eos)
        self.bus.connect('sync-message::element', self.on_sync_message)
##############################################################################
#VIDEO Pipeline
#|
#|
#V
##############################################################################
    def Video_pipeline(self):
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
        self.tcpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('tcpclientsrc','tcpsrc')
        self.tcpsrc.set_property("host", '192.168.1.9')
        self.tcpsrc.set_property("port", 5000)

        self.gdepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('gdpdepay', 'gdepay')


        self.rdepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtph264depay', 'rdepay')

        self.avdec = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_h264', 'avdec')

        self.vidconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert', 'vidconvert')

        self.asink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autovideosink', 'asink')
        self.asink.set_property('sync', False)
        #self.asink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
        #self.set_property('drop', True)

        self.pipeline.add(self.tcpsrc)
        self.pipeline.add(self.gdepay)

        self.pipeline.add(self.avdec)

        self.pipeline.add(self.rdepay)

        self.pipeline.add(self.vidconvert)
        self.pipeline.add(self.asink)

        self.tcpsrc.link(self.gdepay)
        self.gdepay.link(self.rdepay)
        self.rdepay.link(self.avdec)
        self.avdec.link(self.vidconvert)
        self.vidconvert.link(self.asink)
##############################################################################
#^
#|
#|
#VIDEO Pipeline
##############################################################################

    def on_sync_message(self, bus, message):
        if message.get_structure().get_name() == 'prepare-window-handle':
            message.src.set_property('force-aspect-ratio', True)
            message.src.set_window_handle(self.winId)

    def quit(self, container):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.pipeline_A.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_eos(self, bus, msg):
        print('on_eos(): seeking to start of video')
        self.pipeline.seek_simple(
            Gst.Format.TIME,        
            Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH | Gst.SeekFlags.KEY_UNIT,
            0
        )

    def on_error(self, bus, msg):
        print('on_error():', msg.parse_error())

    def start(self):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.pipeline_A.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.showMaximized()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    window.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this code worked fine in my ubuntu system. It shows the streamed video and a button on that. BUT when I run this code on Raspberry Pi, a window is shown for a moment and then Its gone.

I get these warnings on Ubunu:

> (DO2.py:7495): GStreamer-WARNING **:
>   gstpad.c:4506:store_sticky_event: Sticky event
>   misordering, got 'segment' before 'caps'
>
> (DO2.py:7495): GStreamer-WARNING **:
>   gstpad.c:4506:store_sticky_event: Sticky event
>   misordering, got 'segment' before 'caps'

and these on Raspberry :

> qgtkstyle was unable to detect the current gtk (DO2.py:7495):
>
> GStreamer-WARNING **: gstpad.c:4506:store_sticky_event:
>   Sticky event misordering, got 'segment' before 'caps'
>
> (DO2.py:7495): GStreamer-WARNING **:
>   gstpad.c:4506:store_sticky_event: Sticky event
>   misordering, got 'segment' before 'caps' Segmentation fault

Please help me with the problem or guid me how to design a GUI to work in Raspberry.
thanks a lot

Comment: you should try to use [queue](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html)s - it not only makes a buffer between elements but also moves further processing in different thread.. put one before tcpserversink, one after tcpclientsrc and another one after rtph264depay .. it may help you .. but it also may not make any difference - hth