# Why does my pyqt pygst (python gstreamer) code render unreliably?

Tags: python, qt, gstreamer

TLDR: I'm using PyQt and embedding pygst rendering into a window. When I moved all of my systems to Ubuntu 16.04 (from 14 I think?) the pygst rendering in the Qt app no longer works reliably. Depending on the system, I get either a blank window or what looks like an uninitialized memory buffer rendering.

For example, the code works more often on my carbon X1 (using nvidia driver) to render the test source, but only works on my T61P if I use nouveau video driver, and not very reliably. The T61P never works with nvidia driver.

My [original test code is for pygst 0.1](https://gist.github.com/JohnDMcMaster/44b19eb9c36f86341062c31f52714cfc). I [tried porting to pygst 1.0](https://gist.github.com/JohnDMcMaster/fdedc262feebc44d0ce8399ad7652b38) but it doesn't seem to make a difference. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772870/gstreamer-with-python-and-pyqt-does-not-work-very-well) suggests adding queues. I tried adding some, but I didn't get any noticeable difference. But the thread also didn't give very specific (or confident) advice, so I wouldn't discount I didn't know where to add them.

One interesting experiment, as noted in the linked examples, is that delaying player.set_state(PLAYING) or swapping the order of the QMainWindow.show() vs player.set_state(PLAYING) effects the reliability.

EDIT: I think I've solved it! Or at least things are working as well as they did before. Observation: on one of my systems, the problem is considerably worse after ssh -X'ing to my beagle bone black (BBB) and running the LinuxCNC GUI (renders over ssh using OpenGL). Upon recalling, remembered that the T61 BBB I was testing against had libgl1-mesa-swx11 (software OpenGL rendering) to try to work around a rendering issue with the Ubuntu 16.04 nvidia driver. However, it seems that BBB software OpenGL somehow messes up gstreamer on the T61 until the T61 reboots. At this point I don't have a clear resolution, but I do have a solid understanding of what caused the regression. T61 seems to work now on both Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 12.04. I'm going to try to accept the answer below as, although it didn't solve the issue, it did provide some useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the 'unreliable' one is simply incorrect - drawing overlay video to a window that is hidden is at best going to not work, and at worst could cause errors in the sink that stop the pipeline. When it does work it's because the race condition is working in your favour.

You don't need the sync message handler at all; just show() your window and set the window handle on the sink before starting the pipeline.

As for the failure on one platform, try using 0 as the window handle (so the sink creates its own) to bisect the problem. If it doesn't work then overlay video is probably not going to work with that driver at all. Try qwidgetvideosink.

Comment: Eliminated the sync. Code simpler, but behaves the same (works on X1, not well on T61). 0 seems to show the window. I'll look into qwidgetvideosink, but I don't see any quick python examples on it, so it might take me a while to work it out.